# Ruby on Rail error installing SQLite, permissions problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sqlite

I've installed Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.1 on my Mac OS X Leopard. However I wasn't able to install the SQLite gem. I've seen plenty solutions here, but none of the workout for me. Every time I tried to bundle my app I get this error when it comes to the SQLite gem:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied -/Users/eduardoribeiro/sites/models/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.4/API_CHANGES.rdoc
An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm running

```
$ sudo bundle install
```

It seems that the compiler it's trying to install the sqlite dependecies inside of the folder of my app. I had the PATH correctly defined and even created a .bash_profile in the root of Mac OS X.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'` at all before running `bundle install` ?

That could be your problem, if not try `sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.4'` then `bundle install` again.

Comment: Also, don't use sudo with `bundle install`. It says so right in the bundle-install documentation: http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html